# Using JQ to replace a value with another value from the same dictionary

Tags: jq

Given the following JSON file foo.js (stripped down for clarity):

```
{"a":{"b":[{"x":{"x1":1},"y":{"y1":5}},{"x":{"x1":1},"y":{"y1":6}}]}}
```

I want to replace the value of x1 with the corresponding value of y1. That is, I want to end up with:

```
{"a":{"b":[{"x":{"x1":5},"y":{"y1":5}},{"x":{"x1":6},"y":{"y1":6}}]}}
```

This replaces the values, but returns only the modified dictionaries rather than the complete JSON file:

```
% jq -Mc '.a.b[] | .x.x1 = .y.y1' foo.js
{"x":{"x1":5},"y":{"y1":5}}
{"x":{"x1":6},"y":{"y1":6}}
```

This works to replace x1 with a constant value:

```
% jq -Mc '(.a.b[] | .x.x1) |= 9' foo.js
{"a":{"b":[{"x":{"x1":9},"y":{"y1":5}},{"x":{"x1":9},"y":{"y1":6}}]}}
```

But this attempt to use the same idea doesn't work:

```
% jq -Mc '(.a.b[] | .x.x1) |= .y.y1' foo.js
jq: error (at foo.js:1): Cannot index number with string "y"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it.  Use this:

```
.a.b[] |= (.x.x1 = .y.y1)
```

We want to update every item in the `.a.b` array where `.x.x1` takes the value of `.y.y1`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Now to plug it back into the real data file.